# C++ concatenate two unsigned char*

Tags: c++, char, memcpy, unsigned

I have two unsigned char* and trying two concatenate. Here is the sample of code.

```
unsigned char* finaleResult = (unsigned char*)malloc(size);
memcpy(finaleResult, part1, sizeof(part1));
memcpy(finaleResult+sizeof(part1), part2, sizeof(part2));
finaleResult[sizeof(part1) + sizeof(part2)+1] = '\0';
std::cout << "finaleResult: " << finaleResult << std::endl;
```

I assume to see two part1 + part2 in the finaleResult but there is only part1.
What is wrong with my code?

Comment: We can't see how `part`, `part1`, and `part2` are defined. Please show a [mre].

Comment: Please post more code, including where you define and populate `part1, part2`.  I suspect that you may want `strlen` instead of `sizeof`.

Comment: Note that if `part1` is an `unsigned char *`, `sizeof(part1)` will give you the size of the pointer, not the size of the string.  If you want the length of the string, use `strlen`

Comment: @NateEldredge `strlen` wants a `char*` argument, not `unsigned char*`. C-style strings are arrays of plain `char`. If you want to work with nul-terminated arrays of `unsigned char`, you can do that, but the standard library won't necessarily be of much help.

Comment: [None of this is necessary](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c5583c7a6d1cfcf3)

Comment: I am using some third party code input is two unsigned char*. Output also should be unsigned char*.

Comment: The solution I provided gives you the `unsigned char*`.  Just use `c_str()` to get it.

Comment: If you print out raw data for debugging purposes, you should probably print it in hex, and *not* keep it in anything like a string, be it the C or C++ flavor of string. C strings end at the first zero byte, which might cut your debugging output short. You *can* have embedded zero bytes in C++ strings, but you need to be careful how you construct those strings or you might, again, lose some of that data. All in all, your question needs more context, as we are looking at a [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) here.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using C++, there is no need to do any manual memory management for string-like data and doing manipulations such as concatenation.

The [std::basic_string](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) template provides functions that do the concatenation for you.  All you have to do is supply the type as a template argument to `std::basic_string`.

Since the type is `unsigned char`, using `std::basic_string<unsigned char>` gives you concatenation right out-of-the-box:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::basic_string<unsigned char> part1 = {'a','b','c'};
    std::basic_string<unsigned char> part2 = {'1','2','3'};
    std::basic_string<unsigned char> finaleResult = part1 + part2; // magic
    std::cout << finaleResult.c_str();
}
```

Output:

```
abc123
```

Comment: This gets funny once you try working with values outside the 0x00-0x7f range... ;-)

Comment: Yes, I know.  It isn't print/cout friendly.  But the data is there.

Comment: Actually a character constant in that range (e.g. `'ß'`) will flat-out refuse to compile... as the OP clarified that this is meant to be data and the printout just for debugging purposes, it should probably be a `vector< unsigned char >` instead, printed in hex... but that would require yet more clarification.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. One question please
How can I convert finaleResult to unsigned char* correctly?

Comment: Trying...to..type..that...character... These stupid English keyboards.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: US keyboard, US International Alternate layout. My personal recommendation for people working with international texts **and** source on a regular basis. ;-)

Comment: I'll take note of it.  Haven't done any work with international text in years.

Comment: @Lilit -- The `unsigned char*` is `c_str()`.  Or it can be `&finaleResult[0]` if the string is not empty.

Answer (score -1):

There are many issues with this code.

`unsigned char *` is not meant to point at a C string. If you are working with strings in C, you are expected to use plain `char *`. `unsigned char *` is generally considered to be pointing at raw data.

---

**Strings**

In **C**, you would use `strcpy` and `strcat` to copy / concatenate strings, respectively. Make sure your destination has enough memory `malloc`'ed to contain the concatenated string, plus the null terminator.

In **C++**, you do none of the above. No `malloc`, no `memcpy` or `strcpy` or `strcat`, and no pointers. You `#include <string>` and use the `std::string` class.

```
std::string finaleResult{ part1 };
finaleResult += part2;
std::cout << "finaleResult: " << finaleResult << std::endl;
```

---

**Data**

Later on you confirmed in comments that you are, indeed, handling raw data here. We don't really see what `part1` and `part2` and `size` are, so there's some guesswork involved, but I assume that somewhere in `part1`, in the very least at `finalResult[ sizeof( part1 ) ]`, you got a zero byte, which makes `std::cout` stop the output.

Similar as with strings (see above), in C++ you should not work with C primitives (arrays, `malloc`, owning pointers) when handling raw data.

If you **have** to use dynamic memory allocation, use [`std::unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) to get a smart pointer that releases the memory upon destruction (e.g. in case of an exception being thrown).

But generally, you will fare better with [`<vector>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), which relieves you from the burden of managing any resources by hand:

```
vector< unsigned char > finaleResult { part1, part1 + sizeof part1 };
finaleResult.insert( result.end(), part2, part2 + sizeof part2 );
```

To avoid funny business with embedded zero bytes, characters outside ASCII-7 range, and generally data that isn't supposed to be interpreted as string, use hex output:

```
int elements { 0 };
int const elements_per_line { 4 };

for ( auto && c : finaleResult )
{
    std::cout << std::hex << std::setfill( '0' ) << std::setw( 2 ) << static_cast< int >( c ) << " ";

    if ( ( ++elements % elements_per_line ) == 0 )
    {
        std::cout << std::endl;
        elements = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Neither part of the answer, while being correct, answers the root cause of the observed behavior.

Comment: @SergeyA: The root cause of the observed behavior is that OP is using C strings, and wrongly at that, in a C++ program. The solution **is** `<string>`.

Comment: You seem to be making assumptions which do not appear to be grounded in the question text when taken at a face value. For example, nothing in the question tells us that OP really wants to work with standard C strings. Perhaps the data is best represented with `unsigned char`?

Comment: @SergeyA: If the data is "best represented with `unsigned char`", it's not a string.

Comment: Yes, and I do not see OP claiming it's a string anywhere in the question text.

Comment: @SergeyA: The last two lines of the example make it absolutely clear that the OP **is** assuming this to be a string.

Comment: I am using some third party code input is two unsigned char*. Output also should be unsigned char*.

Comment: I do not see how you are making this connection. OP is **trying** to print this to the terminal, perhaps for debugging purposes?

Comment: Yes printing is just debugging

Comment: And the OP said, they do not expect it to be a string. I suggest you edit your answer (or rather remove, since there is really not enough data to answer it).

Comment: @SergeyA: It was late yesterday. See updated answer; better?